# Displaying images from firebase to my android application in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKieY.png)----------

I've been trying to show all the images stored in firebase in an android application using recyclerview. Is there a way to do so? 
I uploaded the photos I want to show in firebase storage and its download URL in firebase database. Each image has a primary ID. I don't know how I can get access to all the child elements of all the primary ID.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: I see downloadurl. Why are you just not using that?

Answer (score 0):

if using a fragment you can do I like below on your `on create` method

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, AllUsersViewHolder>
                (AllUsers.class, R.layout.all_users_display_layout, AllUsersViewHolder.class, databaseReference) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(AllUsersViewHolder viewHolder, AllUsers model, final int position) {

                viewHolder.setThumbImage(getContext(), model.getThumbImage());

            }
        };
        all_user_list.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

and create a `static class` that extends from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` like below

```
public static class AllUsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View view;

        public AllUsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
        }

        public void setThumbImage(final Context context, final String thumb_image) {
            final CircleImageView all_user_image = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.all_user_image);

            if(!thumb_image.equals("default_image")) {
                Picasso.with(context).load(thumb_image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image).into(all_user_image, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Picasso.with(context).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_image).into(all_user_image);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

and create a `helper class` like below

```
public class AllUsers {

    public String thumb_image;

    public AllUsers() {

    }

    public AllUsers(String thumb_image) {

        this.thumb_image = thumb_image;
    }

    public String getThumbImage() {
        return thumb_image;
    }

    public void setThumbImage(String thumb_image) {
        this.thumb_image = thumb_image;
    }


}
```

after that you can retrieve your images to your recycler view

Comment: If you have an problem please let me know